# Unable to perform parallel execution on safari on mac using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I have around 1600 java TCs written using selenium.
While executing test scripts in parallel (say thread count = 5), I am able to trigger 5 safari webdrivers and scripts are executing parallel.

But, when the 6th (threadcount +1) script gets invoked, it is throwing below exception:

**Could not create a session: The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session.**

I am quitting and closing the webdriver session after each test case.
The same piece of code is working fine for other browsers except safari.It should run on the same machine with 5 instances running parallel.

Comment: Are you sure you are able to create 5 safari sessions parallel? As safari does not support parallel session

Comment: yes..I am able to create 5 instances of safari driver in single machine and all 5 run parallel.However,the 6th script is not getting picked up

Comment: Hi @hnayan could you please help me with the Setup details that you used to run the parallel safari in one machine

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you're hitting default `maxSession` limit of `5` browser instances.

You can double check it by opening your Selenium Grid console and looking into node configuration:

[image]

The value can be ramped up by providing the relevant `maxSession` parameter to your Selenium Grid Node startup command line like:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -maxSession 10 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

References:

- [Selenium Grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)
- [Selenium Grid - Configuring the nodes - Optional Parameters](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#optional-parameters)
- [How to run your Selenium tests in Distributed Test Execution Environments](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/selenium_distributed_test_execution_environments/)

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but in case anyone comes across it, please read official apple website:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/about_webdriver_for_safari

> Only one Safari browser instance can be active at any given time, and
> only one WebDriver session at a time can be attached to the browser
> instance. These constraints ensure that the simulated behavior (mouse,
> keyboard, touch, and so forth) accurately reflects what a user can do
> in a macOS

At the moment, safari does not support parallel execution.  It would only be possible if you ran them each inside their own containers (with one Safari instance running inside each container)

I too, thought I had 5 parallel Safari sessions running localy at first, but when you watch them, they only execute one at a time, changing maxSession will not fix this

-- I hope this helps someone