# Safari does not support execution of automation scripts on multiple thread,

Tags: selenium, pytest, python-multithreading, safaridriver, parallel-execution

Safari does not support execution of automation scripts on multiple threads, Please let me know if there are any alternatives to run selenium tests in parallel. I am running tests in parallel on other browsers like chrome and firefox. The Framework is developed in python using pytest and I am using pytest-xdist to run the scripts in parallel. I also tried pytest-parallel but even this did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched other related threads? 
Example thread from about 8 months ago: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670744/unable-to-perform-parallel-execution-on-safari-on-mac-using-selenium)

Paraphrased quote from there:

> My expectation is that you're hitting default `maxSession` limit of
>   `5` browser instances.
>
> You can double check it by opening your Selenium Grid console and
>   looking into node configuration:
>
> The value can be ramped up by providing the relevant `maxSession`
>   parameter to your Selenium Grid Node startup command line like:
>
> ```
> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -maxSession 10 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
>                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> References